# how do i display a message if user puts a non existing sub command?

Tags: discord.py

So I made a sub command that just sends a message back. I found that if the user types a non existing command it still displays the message from the sub command. It sounds confusing but here's an example.

```
User: ;id
Bot: This command help you find the name of anyone in the server! 
User: ;id Slayer
Bot: Bob Miller
```

So while testing I found if the user sends some thing like **;id jgfjkag** the bot still sends the original message for **;id** which is **"This command help you find the name of anyone in the server!"**. How would I make the bot send a specific message if the user trys to use a non existing sub command? Here's the code:

```
@commands.group()
  async def id(self, ctx):
    if ctx.invoked_subcommand is None:
     await ctx.send("This command help you find the name of anyone in the server! ")

  @id.command()
  async def Slayer(self, ctx):
    await ctx.send("Bob Miller")
  
  @id.command()
  async def Skel(self, ctx):
    await ctx.send("John Dove")
```

Answer (score 2):

Check [`ctx.subcommand_passed`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context.subcommand_passed) first:

```py
@commands.group()
async def id(self, ctx):
    if ctx.subcommand_passed is None:
        await ctx.send("This command help you find the name of anyone in the server!")
    elif ctx.invoked_subcommand is None:
        await ctx.send(f"Subcommand '{ctx.subcommand_passed}' does not exist.")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my favorite method of doing it:

```py
@commands.group(invoke_without_command=True)
async def group(self, ctx):
    await ctx.send_help(ctx.command)  # invokes the help command for the group

@group.command()
async def subcommand(self, ctx):
    await ctx.send("You passed a valid subcommand!")
```

The invoke_without_command parameter, when set to true, will only call the command if there are no (valid) subcommands passed. This means that if the code inside if the group() function is called, you can safely assume that they didn't pass a subcommand (or passed an invalid one).

I also like to use [ctx.send_help](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=context%20send_help#discord.ext.commands.Context.send_help), since that will automatically list subcommands. You could replace this with something like:

```py
    await ctx.send("You didn't pass a valid subcommand!")
```

### [EDIT]

More careful reading of your question revealed that the subcommand already has some functionality. This makes it more difficult, but this will work:

```py
@commands.group(invoke_without_command=True, ignore_extra=False)
async def group(self, ctx):
    await ctx.send("This is a group command!")

@group.error
async def on_group_error(self, ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.TooManyArguments):
        await ctx.send("You passed an invalid subcommand!")

@group.command()
async def subcommand(self, ctx):
    await ctx.send("You passed a VALID subcommand!")
```

Here is what it would look like:

```
!group
Bot: This is a group command!
!group bla
Bot: You passed an invalid subcommand!
!group subcommand
Bot: You passed a VALID subcommand!
```

NOTE: The ignore_extra field raises the commands.TooManyArguments error, which then invokes the error handler allowing the bot to send the error message. Unfortunately, the default on_command_error hook will still be called. I would suggest ignoring the `commands.TooManyArguments` error inside of your main error handler to fix this.